# Separate text input that contains commas "," into different array objects

Tags: javascript

When a user inputs the name of the players, I want my code to separate each player into a different object in my array. My code detects when commas "," are part of the text, but how can I use those commas "," to separate each player name into an individual object in my array.

```js
var subject = [];

function addSubjects() {
namesInputted = document.getElementById('namesInputter').value;

  if (namesInputted.includes(',') == true){
    //HERE IS THE CODE I AM MISSING!!!
  }else{
  subject.push(namesInputted);
  document.getElementById('namesInputter').value = null;
  console.log(subject);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <h1>RETOS LOCOS</h1>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="namesInputter" placeholder="Player Name" value="">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addSubjectsButton" onclick="addSubjects()">Add Player</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="startGameButton" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it does. What should I do if a question answers my question already?

Comment: It should prompt you to accept the duplicate question; if not, just wait, others will come along and vote the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should use the `split` function:

```
if (namesInputted.includes(',') == true) {
  namesInputted.split(",").forEach(function(name) {
    subject.push(name);
    console.log(name);
  });
  document.getElementById('namesInputter').value = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `string` by commas into an `array`. Then you iterate each element and you `push()` it into your array. I also trimmed each result before appending it to get rid of any whitespaces in between.

```js
var subject = [];

function addSubjects() {
namesInputted = document.getElementById('namesInputter').value;

  if (namesInputted.includes(',') == true){
    namesInputted.split( ',' ).forEach( function( item ) {
      subject.push( item.trim() );
    } );
    console.log(subject);
  }else{
  subject.push(namesInputted);
  document.getElementById('namesInputter').value = null;
  console.log(subject);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <h1>RETOS LOCOS</h1>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="namesInputter" placeholder="Player Name" value="">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addSubjectsButton" onclick="addSubjects()">Add Player</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="startGameButton" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
    </div>
```